HAProxy configuration issue with DNS replacement leading to 401 Unauthorized error from Azure IoT Hub
I 'm using HAProxy to forward requests to Azure IoT Hub, but I'm encountering an issue 401 Unauthorized error from the IoT Hub. The error response includes the iothuberrorcode as IoTHubNotFound. I am able to ping and do nslookup from the server successfully where the HAProxy is running, only with haproxy I am getting error.
This is my haproxy.cfg:
frontend iothub_frontend
  bind *:443
  mode tcp
  default_backend iothub_backend
backend iothub_backend
  mode tcp
  server iothub <<iothub-name>>.azure-devices.net:443
  http-request set-header Host <<iothub-name>>.azure-devices.net


Refer to this link for DNS resolution

@Sampath, any idea how to use it with tcp mode?

To resolve the 401 Unauthorized error in HAProxy requests while connecting to Azure IoT Hub, configure SSL termination and bind the certificate to port 443 as shown below:
bind *:443 ssl crt /etc/ssl/mydomain/mydomain.pem alpn h2,http/1.1



Create  X.509 certificates and use that as Authentication with  Azure IoT Hub in happroxy.

Refer to this guide for detailed instructions on configuring an SSL certificate in HAProxy.
Add SSL/TLS parameters to ensure secure protocols are used. Include the minimum SSL version directive as shown below:
bind *:443 ssl crt /etc/ssl/mydomain/mydomain.pem alpn h2,http/1.1 ssl-min-ver TLSv1.2


For protocol versions use TLSv1.2 for 1.2 and use TLSv1.1 for 1.1
Below is an example of an haproxy.cfg configuration:

frontend iothub_frontend
  bind *:443 ssl crt /etc/haproxy/cert.pem   configured
  mode http
  option httplog
  option forwardfor
  default_backend iothub_backend

backend iothub_backend
  mode http
  server iothub <<iothub-name>>.azure-devices.net:443 ssl verify none
  http-request set-header Host <<iothub-name>>.azure-devices.net
  http-request set-header Authorization "SharedAccessSignature sr=<<iothub-name>>.azure-devices.net&sig=<<signature>>&se=<<expiry>>&skn=iothubowner"


To verify the connection with Azure IoT Hub, run the following command:
openssl s_client -connect <<iothub-name>>.azure-devices.net:443

Output:

